In which dimensions is it possible to define supersymmetric actions?
Susy gauge theories only exist in dimensions 3,4,6,10. This is stated by Baez and Huerta as:

Nonabelian Yang-Mills fields minimally coupled to massless spinors are
supersymmetric if and only if the dimension of spacetime is 3, 4, 6 or
10.

and some lecture notes, such as Tong's (see pg 43), argue this impossibility explicitly for photon and photino, so also abelian theories are only possible in dimensions 3, 4, 6, 10.
See also Brink-Schwarz-Scherk 1977 that argues 2,4,6,10.
A recent reference here is Townsend's Hullfest talk, see slide 7 in https://plato.tp.ph.ic.ac.uk/conferences/hull60/Talks/PKT.Hullfest.pdf
This is of course for field theories in Minkowski space-time; I guess it is the same for relativistic quantum mechanics, but my question is for quantum field theory.
But of course, gauge theories are not the only possible field theories. One wonders what about not interacting theories with just susy pairs of scalars and fermion. Or what about other non-gauge interactions. As a minimum requisite, does a pair of free weyl fermion + complex scalar exist in any number of dimensions? Does a massive massive superparticle exist?
So the general question is not for which dimensions do SYM theories exist, but what kinds of supersymmetric actions exist, if any, in each number of dimensions.

I don't see how this would ever be a problem for free theories. Are you asking for the supersymmetry to also hold off-shell?

Well, it is not intuitive neither why it would be a problem for gauge theories, and it is.

Comments to the post (v4): 1. Consider to only ask 1 question. 2. Is the question about field theory or point particles? 3. Also consider to provide references for claims. Which Tong notes? Which pages?

@Qmechanic I am truly asking only one question: in which dimensions it is possible to define supersymmetric actions

A brief note first: The paper by Baez and Huerta does not state that there are no supersymmetric gauge theories in other dimensions than the ones you mentioned, but that the specific Lagrangian they look at is only supersymmetric in these cases [Which they did not prove by the way, they proved the other implication]. There are gauge invariant and supersymmetric theories in other dimensions (See references here for examples).
By Nahm's theorem, the maximal dimension of Super Yang Mills theory is 10, see for example here, since otherwise the theory would necessarily contain particles with spin greater than one. For other theories, I am sure similar considerations could apply.
I cannot think of any other restrictions on the top of my head. What Tong did in his lecture notes was proving that the bosonic and fermonic degrees of freedom must be the same, but by adding other bosonic or fermonic fields this can, I believe, always be achieved (Tong restricted themselves to one spinor and one gauge boson).

I was not sure if this was a complete answer (for instance, what happens with free theories?) but the key statement here is that the statement of Baez Huerta etc is very restrictive.
